# Bandwidth Problem in Terminal?

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to install the Mac cursors to Ubuntu 12.04 but i get this error when using the wget command in Terminal.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget -O mac-cursors.zip http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53319850/NoobsLab.com/mac-cursors.zip
--2012-12-09 16:31:17--  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53319850/NoobsLab.com/mac-cursors.zip
Resolving dl.dropbox.com (dl.dropbox.com)... 23.21.195.136, 23.23.139.153, 107.20.134.231, ...
Connecting to dl.dropbox.com (dl.dropbox.com)|23.21.195.136|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 509 Bandwidth Error
2012-12-09 16:31:18 ERROR 509: Bandwidth Error.
```

Can someone tell me what this means please, and a possible workaround? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** You can't really do anything except find a different download, or ask the NoobsLab.com to upgrade their Dropbox account.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error:

> **509 Bandwidth Limit Exceeded (Apache bw/limited extension)**
>       This status code, while used by many servers, is not specified in any RFCs.

This is a server issue. This occurred because the server has hit the limit for bandwidth, most likely due to high traffic on that user's public stuff. Dropbox actually limits the bandwidth public stuff can use and will return Error 509 when this bandwidth is exceeded due to over-sharing.

If you visit http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53319850/NoobsLab.com/mac-cursors.zip, you get this descriptive error message.

> ### Error (509)
>
> This account's public links are generating too much traffic and have been temporarily disabled!

Therefore, you can't do anything about it except wait for the rate limit to pass, or find a different download.

Comment: Just as ObsessiveSSOℲ said, the problem has nothing to do with Ubuntu or `wget`, see https://www.dropbox.com/help/45/en

Comment: @Haozhun This post is over 6 months old.